# supply chain analytics dataset?

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning

I need to develop a model which enhances the supply chain and reduces the cost and wastage for perishable products like meat, seafood, dairy products and fruits and vegetables etc. Could someone please guide me how to get the dataset for this purpose!

Comment: this sounds like a risk management problem.   how much spoilage a day are you at risk for given a certain set of features.   you start by examining the ranges where spoilage could occur after gathering the data.  next you calculate the risk of spoilage in pounds or tons.   It is similar to portfolio analysis

Comment: yes, modeling would be on similar lines to portfolio analysis. Could you please suggest how to get dataset for it ?

Comment: try looking for a dataset at uci

Comment: thanks for the suggestion :)